# How do I share a sqlite database from my iOS project to my WatchKit Extension?

Tags: mmwormhole

How do I share a sqlite database from my iOS project to my WatchKit Extension using MMWormhole in objc?

Answer (score 3):

MMWormhole is meant for passing individual messages and snippets of data between your app and an extension; it does not cover your use case of sharing an entire SQLite database.

In watch OS 1 you can put the SQLite database into [a shared container](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6).

In watch OS 2 this isn't possible anymore as the extension is running in a different device. You could [transfer the file using `WCSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/transferFile:metadata:), but you might want to rethink your architecture so that sending small messages between the phone and watch is sufficient rather than transmitting the full SQLite database.